# integration of $\log^a\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I was trying the following problem proposed by our teacher:

**Let $f\in L^p(0,1)$ for some $p\in(1,\infty)$. Prove that $g(x)=f(x)\log^s\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\in L^1(0,1)$, where $s\in\mathbb{R}$.**

The only reasonable approach for this probem seems to apply Hölder's inequality. Applying holder's inequality with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ I got the following:

$$\int_0^1g(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)\log^s\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)dx\leq\left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^pdx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\int_0^1\left\vert\log^s\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right\vert^qdx\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
Hence, since $f\in L^p(0,1)$ we have that $h(x)=\log^{s}\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\in L^q(0,1)$ implies $g\in L^1(0,1)$ , so our problem reduces to prove that $h\in L^q(0,1)~\forall~q\in(0,\infty)$, but I don't have any idea on how to study $h$. Probably we have to distinguish between $s>0$ and $s<0$ or sth like that but I'm quite lost.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that $\log$ is not integrable between $(0,1)$ due to the singularity at zero. Therefore, if $g$ is indeed in $L^1$, the above *if and only if* statement is not true. Since you're dealing with $\log$ between $(0,1)$, you should try to **cancel out** the singularity at zero by multiplying the logarithm by something like $x$.

Comment: @spaceman I added more details of what i've tried. I don't understand you, because multiplying by $x$ will make a factor $\frac{1}{x}$ appear in the integral of $f(x)$ and we are working with $p>1$ so $\frac{1}{x^p}$ diverges in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give you just a hint, then in some hours I'll add more details.

Recall that therre is this kind of known integral: for which values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ does the integral $$\int\limits_0^{1}\frac{dx}{x^{\alpha}|\ln^{\beta}(x)|}$$ converge? *If and only if $\alpha < 1$ and for any value of $\beta$ or $\alpha =1$ and $\beta > 1$.*

and what about $$\int\limits_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{\alpha}|\ln^{\beta}(x)|}$$ *If and only if $\alpha > 1$ and for any value of $\beta$ or $\alpha =1$ and $\beta > 1$.*

Now, note that Hölder inequality is not giving you necessary conditions to be able to say this integral converges. ***If*** you find some values for which the rhs of your equation is finite, then the lhs is finite as well. But this is not necessary at all. Hence, my hint is to try to generalize the second formula I gave you above to your case with $f \in L^p(0,1)$.

> Hint no.2: multiply and divide by $x^p$, put one term together with your function $f$ and use the other for convergence.

Comment: Hmm, that's a really nice idea, I'll try and let u know whether I am able to solve it or not, thanks